# C# Thread Exception Error

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I am working in C# and adding threading to a set of server code. What it does is accept any clients, if there are any pending connections and then creates a client handle thread for handling messages from clients.

The problem is my code throws an exception when a client connects and the thread is created. I've debugged it down enough to know it's the thread itself, but I have no idea why. I thought I handled it correctly. The code works without handling the thread, so I am not sure what is going wrong:
Quick Note: NetTcp_Acpt is a List< TcpClient > and NetTcp_Thrd is a List< Thread >.

```
        try {
            if ( NetTcp_Sock.Pending() == true ) {
                //Asynchronously accept the client;
                TcpClient myClient = await NetTcp_Sock.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                NetTcp_Acpt.Add( myClient );
                int myID = NetTcp_Acpt.Count;

                //Create new thread to handle client data;
                Thread myThread = new Thread( () => Net_Handle( myClient , Convert.ToString( myID ) , myID ) );
                myThread.Name = Convert.ToString( myID );
                NetTcp_Thrd.Add( myThread );
                myThread.Start();

                Console.WriteLine( "Client: " + Convert.ToString( myID ) + " connected!" );
            }
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            //NOTE:Exception always thrown, result of: Client Threads on lines 31 to 34;
            //Excepion needs fixing;
            Console.WriteLine( ex.ToString() );
        }
```

Comment: Another quick note: Method Net_Handle( TcpClient , String , Int ) has no code. It simply holds the parameters for now.

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Good Question: This is from the Output Window: `A first chance exception of type System.NullReferenceException occurred in GMS_Server.exe`. This is from the exception in the console: `at GMS_Server.Net_Assets.<Net_Accept>d__3.MoveNext() in c:\User\Username\Documents\ Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GMS_Server\GMS_Server\Net_Server.cs::line 29`. Line 29 is the "NetTcp_Acpt.Add( myClient )" line. Which doesn't seem relevant... because removing the 4 lines of thread code keeps the exception from being thrown.

Comment: Apparently it is the adding to the client collection that fails. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `NetTcp_Acpt` collection has been initialized before adding the **client**.

Initializing means something like:

```
NetTcp_Acpt = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TcpClient>();
```

That is what is missing in your code.

Comment: That's the problem, it was initiated before hand in the same class:
http://pastebin.com/2VtbqzLE

Comment: @FatalSleep - See the addition to my answer. You declared the variable but did not initialize it.

Comment: Wow! How could I miss something that crucial?? Thank you!

Comment: It is easy to miss. One thing that I found very helpful is to read the exception messages. Years ago compilers were not that helpful so I learned to ignore them but these days the messages are quite accurate.

Comment: I try to read them, but I am still a bit new to C#, so I miss things here and there with the  errors.